# AWS API Gateway OPTIONS Request Headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

My API has an OPTIONS method that is implemented through a Mock integration that is set to return the required CORS headers.

The problem is that it returns `500 Internal Server Error` when there is no `Content-Type` set on the OPTIONS request. It is returning proper CORS headers with a `200 Success` when `Content-Type` is set to `application/json`.

How do I fix this as the OPTIONS request is sent by the browser and I don't think I'm allowed to set `Content-Type` header on it?

Answer (score -1):

You can set Content-Type headers in API Gateway. Refer this link I hope it should helps

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: That is for the response headers which I have already set. The problem is my mock implementation errors out when there is no 'Content-Type' header on the request.